# ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T> with StrictNullCheck could be undefined?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have upgraded to TypeScript 2 with strictNullCheck on.

I have an API call

.then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg) => {
   this.myService.setUser(response.data);

I get:

**[ts] Argument of type 'IUser | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IUser'.**
**(property) angular.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg.data: IUser | undefined
6 ERRORS**

Where and why does it say that my success callback could be undefined? (It can't). Now I have to handle this like an error, but if the API failed it wouldn't return a success callback.